# Xubuntu не находит gradle, хотя он установлен и вчера работал

Tags: gradle, xubuntu

Вчера установил `gradle` последней версии и он работал, собирал проекты. До этого стоял `gradle  2.10`. Сейчас при обращении к `gradle` пишет это:

```
Программа 'gradle' на данный момент не установлена. Вы можете установить её, выполнив:
sudo apt install gradle
```

При попытке установить его пишет:

```
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Уже установлен пакет gradle самой новой версии (3.5-0ubuntu1).
Следующие пакеты устанавливались автоматически и больше не требуются:
```

И длинный список пакетов. Но при вызове `gradle` или `gradle -version` по-прежнему говорит, что он не установлен.

Comment: `$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall gradle` пробовали? Покажите вывод `$ whereis -b gradle`.

Comment: @zombic `reinstall` не помог, всё равно не видит. Переустанвка остановилась на это этапе: `Подготовка к распаковке …/gradle_3.5-0ubuntu1_all.deb …
Распаковывается gradle (3.5-0ubuntu1) на замену (3.5-0ubuntu1) …
Настраивается пакет gradle (3.5-0ubuntu1) …
`. Вот вывод whereis `gradle: /usr/lib/gradle /usr/share/gradle`.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать установку с ключом `-f` (--fix-broken): `$ sudo apt-get install -f gradle`. Если не поможет, удалите с таким же ключом : `$ sudo apt-get remove -f gradle` и установите заново. А если и это не поможет, то можно попробовать насильно удалить и после установить пакет: `dpkg --purge --force-depends gradle`.

Comment: @zombic ничего не помогает, при попытке установить с флагом -f пишет `обновлено 0, установлено 0 новых пакетов`, при попытке удалить `Пакет «gradle» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён`, а при попытке удалить насильно `dpkg: предупреждение: игнорируется запрос на удаление неустановленного пакета gradle`

Comment: У меня больше предложений нет. Может @alexanderbarakin подскажет.

Comment: @zombic в любом случае, спасибо за участие:)

Comment: Вроде бы, исправил. Помогло это `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/gradle/default/bin`.